# Any way to create Expresso Store price modifier templates

Tags: expresso-store, modifiers, price-modifier

We're using Expresso Store on a new project and the client has asked as to whether price modifier templates can be created to avoid having staff add modifiers in different ways for different products which share a common modifier type.

Is this even possible? If not I think it would make for a great addition to Store. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing currently in Store that allows you to do something like this. There is currently [Global Product Variations](https://exp-resso.com/support/feature-requests) feature request that would cover exactly what you are looking for.

Having said that if your product modifiers are not adjusting the price, do not require stock levels, or needing separate SKUs (I think those are the only limits) you can create the variations at the template level using text modifiers in your templates.

> The input parameter allows you to use custom product modifiers defined
>   in your template, rather than setting them up on a per-product basis.
>   This is useful if you are selling a large number of similar products.
>
> For example, to allow a Small, Medium and Large size option for every
>   product in your store, add the following parameter to the product tag:
>
> ```
> input:size="Size"
> ```
>
> Then, further down the form, you can use standard HTML to submit the
>   modifier along with the rest of the form:
>
> ```
> <select name="size">
>   <option value="Small">Small</option>
>   <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
>   <option value="Large">Large</option>
> </select>
> ```
>
> These modifiers will behave like any other text modifiers, and display
>   on the checkout and order details pages.

[Complete Documentation](https://exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#input_custom_modifier_name_name)